# How to restrict CEO Voip access

Tags: voip

How can I restrict access to the internal number of the CEO in CUCM?
So that the manager can call everyone, but no one else can call the manager except the secretary.

Comment: Not an answer, as such this is a comment. Usually you have a short extension number and a long phone number. You can call both, but one is hard to remember and the other is not. You can usually also change the number you send out. I'd set that to the secretary's number and remove the short extension. The secretary can have a button on their phone with the long number so she can dial it by pressing that button. As long as no one knows the long number, they can't reach the CEO. 

If the CEO calls out, and someone redials, they get the secretary instead.

Comment: It was a smart suggestion, but I have the experience that when the internals have different numbers of digits, for example, some are 3 digits and some are 4 digits.
When making a call to a smaller (3-digit) extension, the system would be delayed to make sure that another number is not added. @LPChip

Comment: Yes, that is with extensions. But if one calls a real phone number, that delay is not present. Every endpoint has a real phone number next to the extension. You use this real number, not create a longer extension.